# The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have used text as a datatype for device name. while adding the data into the form, it throws an error : The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator

```
try
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into license1 values(@l_id,@customer_id,@d_id,@device_name,@from,@to)", cn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l_id", license_id.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_id", c_comboBox4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d_id", d_id_comboBox4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@device_name", d_name_comboBox5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", DateTime.Parse(date_to.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", DateTime.Parse(date_from.Text));

    cn.Open();
    a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (a > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data Submitted");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: What is `a` in your code ???

Comment: it is just an integer variable

Comment: Do you have any triggers on `license1`? That error can't be coming from that statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to change this line

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@device_name", SqlDbType.Text).Value = d_name_comboBox5.Text;
```

The AddWithValue treats the string values as a NVarChar datatype and looking at error message a Text type is expected.

You could also try to change your column datatype to `nvarchar(MAX)`. The TEXT columns are considered obsolete and will [probably removed in future versions of Sql Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try to change the data type of the `device_name` column to `varchar` and retest your app