# The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator in C#

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I am trying to access the data `empname` from the employeeTable, but the code I have written is giving me the following error:

> The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Please suggest a solution

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Connection = "Data Source=(local);Initial catalog=Test;Integrated Security=true";
    string Query = "SELECT * FROM  EmployeeTable WHERE empname='" + comboBox1.Text + "' ;";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conn);

    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())     
    {
        textBoxEmpName.Text = reader["EmpName"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line you get this error? And use parameterized queries. This kind of string concatenations are open for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: What is the type of `EmployeeTable.empname`?

Comment: What line gives you the error?  Also, learn to use parameterized queries.

Comment: there is also no reason to create temp vars to hold the query results

Comment: when i select the empname in combobox it gives me the error message.

Comment: EmployeeTable.empname type is VARCHAR(50). Patrick Hofman

Comment: EmployeeTable.empname type is VARCHAR(50). @Patrick Hofman

Comment: when i select the empname in combobox it gives me the error message..@johnKoerner

Comment: My problem is solved i just changed the type of empname from text to VARCHAR.. @PatrickHofman

Comment: You just told me three times it is `varchar`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254470/the-data-types-text-and-varchar-are-incompatible-in-the-equal-to-operator)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can't compare text to varchar, but as an answer to anyone in the future with this problem simply convert the text column to varchar for the query.

```
SELECT * FROM  EmployeeTable WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, empname) = '" + comboBox1.Text + "' ;";
```

Always use [**parameters**](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06)

```
SELECT * FROM  EmployeeTable WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, empname) = @comboBox";
```

Comment: Would it also be okay to use LIKE without wildcard?

Comment: In EF core use Convert.ToString(x) that will translate to Convert(nvarchar(max), x) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72758236/ef-core-function-to-pass-as-in-cast-value-as-varchar1024/72759116#72759116

Answer (score 9):

Try using VARCHAR(MAX) if the target string size is not big enough to represent the XML instance.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), empname)
```

Answer (score 2):

xulfi afridi, actually the code should be:

Select * from EmployeeTable Where Cast(empname as varchar(max)) = @combobox

Answer (score 0):

xulfi afridi,

You can use CAST (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#syntax) instead of CONVERT as follows:

CAST (*expression* AS *data_type*[*(length)*]);

So for the solution will be:
Select*from EmployeeTable Where Cast(varchar,empname)='@combobox'