# Updating Records - The Datatypes nvarchar and text are incompatible in the equal to operator

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to update the records in SQL Server using VBA.

```vb
'Required Query
    myQuery = "UPDATE dbo.RecertFormatterDataTable  SET [TaskStatus]  = ? WHERE [TaskName] = ? AND [Report Name] = ?"

    Dim CurrStatus As String
    Dim TaskNames As String
    Dim ReportPath As String        

    'set up parameters
        Set myParameters = New Collection
        myParameters.Add TaskNames
        myParameters.Add CurrStatus
        myParameters.Add ReportPath
        queryType = "Push"

        Set rs = myDB.Query(myQuery, queryType, myParameters)
```

I have a class module which converts String to `advarchar`.

I am not able to load the values here as it says -

> The data types nvarchar and text are incompatible in the equal to operator

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). In short: do ***NOT*** use `text` anymore

Comment: @marc_s Interesting but all the datatypes that I have in my sql server are just nvarchar(255) and not text or varchar or ntext.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888243/the-data-types-text-and-varchar-are-incompatible-in-the-equal-to-operator-in-c-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy/pasted part is not clear to me, but I can say that this kind of errors mostly occur because of forgotten apostrophe (') sign before and after assigning the string value.

**Example:**

WRONG -> `query = ("update myTable set Name = {0} where Id = 10", "Jonathan");`

TRUE ->
`query = ("update myTable set Name = ' + "Jonathan" + ' where Id = 10";`

Thefore, I think something is wrong while assigning value for myQuery. Try something like that:

myQuery = `"UPDATE dbo.RecertFormatterDataTable  SET [TaskStatus]  = '?' WHERE [TaskName] = '?' AND [Report Name] = '?'"`

If above does not help, try:

Solution 1: Change the datatype of ?s to nvarchar.

myQuery = `"UPDATE dbo.RecertFormatterDataTable 
            SET [TaskStatus]  = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ?) WHERE [TaskName] = 
            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ?) AND [Report Name] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ?)"`

Solution 2: Convert the data type of column to nvarchar(max) and rerun the update query.. Example:

```
ALTER TABLE RecertFormatterDataTable
ALTER COLUMN TaskStatus NVARCHAR(MAX)
GO
```

Reference: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/12/04/sql-server-fix-error-402-the-data-types-ntext-and-varchar-are-incompatible-in-the-equal-to-operator/