# EF Core Function to Pass "AS" in `CAST( 'value' AS VARCHAR(1024))`

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, ef-core-6.0

I have a piece of code in EF Core that looks like this:

```cs
var queryPart1 = from table1 in context.Table1
                 select table1.ColA;

var queryPart2 = from table2 in context.Table2
                 select table2.ColX;

var finalQuery = queryPart1.Union(queryPart2);

var result = await finalQuery.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Of course my real code is a bit more complex, but the idea is that EF does not like the `Union` here because although `ColA` and `ColX` are both strings, they have different length.

I'm guessing the right way to solve this is to `CAST` both of them to the length of the longest column or something like that. But I do not want to write the whole query in T-SQL as the it's a bit more complicated than above and could really use LINQ.

I couldn't find a built-in EF Core function that does that when both "from" and "to" types are strings (it does it if you for example cast a string to a date). I  tried to do something like `.Substring(0, 1024)` but it did not work.

I looked into mapping custom function. It might be easy to translate something like
`context.Cast("table1.ColX", "VARCHAR(1024)")` to something like
`CAST(table1.ColX, 'VARCHAR(1024)')`. But this is "not" the correct syntax for `CAST`.

The correct syntax is `CAST(table1.ColX AS VARCHAR(1024))`.
Note the `AS VARCHAR(1024)` bit.

How would I write an EF Core to SQL function translation that does that?

**Note:** ideally the whole bit `VARCHAR(1024)` would be passed as a variable.

Comment: `Convert()` is the same as `Cast` in t-sql but with a function-like style.

Comment: I don't know much about EF, but you may try to use nested queries `SELECT colx AS coly FROM (SELECT CAST(colx AS VARCHAR);`

Answer (score 4):

Try `Convert.ToString(x)` it translates to `Convert(nvarchar(max), x)`

If it doesn't work you will need to make the join in the runtime.

You could also create a View.

Comment: This is awesome. It does not answer the literal question but it did solve my problem. Thanks a lot.